# Could two WD Passport Ultra 1TB drives be used in the OWC Mercury Elite Pro Dual mini enclosure as RAID 1?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, hardware, external-disk, raid

I'm thinking of buying one more [WD Passport Ultra 1TB](http://wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=1235&language=1) (I have one already) so that in the near future I could disassemble the two Passports and install the 1TB drives into the [OWC Mercury Elite Pro Dual mini](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MEQMH0GBK/) (0GB, enclosure only) for a RAID 1 setup.

But from [this](http://youtu.be/2GGTQF6oE3E?t=5m41s) Youtube video of a guy dissembling a 2TB version of the Passport Ultra, he says the "interface is directly soldered onto the drive". Does that mean it won't fit into the OWC enclosure, or in any other enclosures like [this](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/MOTGS3U3/) as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that enclosure accepts 12.5mm drives, those WD Passports have the USB connector built into the drive. They don't have a standard SATA connector and therefore cannot be used in that enclosure.

Comment: Cheers Bert! Do you have any idea if I could still set up a RAID 1 with two identical portable drives?

Comment: Yes you can - the drives don't even need to be identical. Apple has instructions to do this using Disk Utility [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2559)